# what happens if i interpret the stat() attributes when stat() for directory path fails?

Tags: c++, stat

i have a requirement where i need to check a given directory exists or not.

i am doing like this

```
structure stat buf;
stat(dir_path,buf);

if( S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) )
cout << " its a directory " << endl;
else
cout << " its not a directory " << endl;
```

this procedure is not working sometimes.  The output is not consistent for me.

Is it like, i should not perform S_ISDIR() when the stat() call fails ?

because what random behavior i am seeing here is..

stat() for the directory path fails and then i am trying S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)

so, now this S_ISDIR() is not behaving correctly sometimes. why is this happening like this ? any idea ?

Comment: `structure` isn't a valid keyword in c++. Post real code as a [MCVE] please!

Comment: `if(stat(dir_path,buf) == 0 && S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) )` ?

Comment: @BoPersson: You could obtain "it's not a directory" when it is but `stat` failed for some other reason. Not good.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if even `stat` fails there's almost nothing you can do with that path, you should treat that kind of failure somehow like that path just doesn't exist (which may very well be), so even from a logical standpoint the content of `buf` is meaningless. Check the return value and act accordingly.

Comment: yes. stat's return value is -1

Answer (score 3):

If `stat` fails then the values in `buf` will be unspecified, won't they?

I don't see any point in examining them anyway. What possible use could the result be?

Simply don't do this if `stat` fails. You should always check the return value of POSIX functions.

*(I'm surprised to see that the manpages don't make the behaviour clear in this case, though perhaps that's a lesson in itself.)*

Comment: I was about to comment: "did you check stat return value?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Interestingly enough, that the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) doesn't tell you that `buf` is untouched (it is, simply because that's how system calls usually function) upon failure, should give pause. The contents of `buf` are indeed indeterminate after a failed call. And now I want to know, if there's little hacky program somewhere that assumes atomicity.

Comment: @dhke: I'd bet on it ;)